# Creating a tuple of lists in Python

Tags: list, integer, tuples

How do I take an integer and turn it into a tuple of lists using python?
For instance, I have P=(1234) and I want to become ([1],[2],[3],[4]) I would like to do it in recursive form, but any way would help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there something you're specifically having trouble with? Add some code.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a very handy language for transforming data. Basically you only need `map` and a few functions for changing the data type:

```py
>>> tuple(map(lambda i: [i], map(int, str(P))))
([1], [2], [3], [4])
```

This works in Python 2 and 3.